# Zebra ZPL code mixed mode QR data

Tags: mode, zebra-printers, zpl, mixed

This is my complete ZPL code for labels I will be printing. This contains mock data, as the finished code will be concatenated in to Excel for over 1000 labels.

```
^XA
^FO50,30
^ADN,60,50
^FD300957^FS
^FO50,170
^ADN,40,25
^FDGUIDE PIN PANELBOARD^FS
^FO50,240
^ADN,25,15
^FDPOU Location^FS
^FO50,280
^ADN,40,25
^FDD2P^FS
^FO50,370
^ADN,25,15
^FDSupply Location^FS
^FO50,410
^ADN,40,25
^FDW7E02^FS
^FO50,490
^ADN,40,25
^FDBin Qty^FS
^FO50,540
^ADN,50,25
^FD50^FS
^FO650,30
^ADN,25,15
^FDSTORES^FS
^FO650,70
^ADN,25,15
^FDKBLINE^FS
^FO650,110
^ADN,28,15
^FDD2P^FS
^FO450,250^BQ,2,10
^FDD03048F,LA,N300957,ACAGE,AW7E02,ASTORES,AKBLINE,N50^FS
^XZ
```

The line in question is

```
^FDD03048F,LA,N300957,ACAGE,AW7E02,ASTORES,AKBLINE,N50^FS
```

What I need my QR code to do is be in mixed mode with automatic input and take the 6 field entries found in the part "`N300957,ACAGE,AW7E02,ASTORES,AKBLINE,N50`" and plug them in to separate fields when scanned. The data is in the order the fields are in when tabbed through on the inventory form. At this time, when scanned, the QR sends all the data to only the first field in a long string. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Use \09 for Horizontal Tab and \0D for Carriage Return like this:

```
^FDD03048F,LA,N300957\09ACAGE\09AW7E02\09ASTORES\09AKBLINE\09N50\0D^FS
```

You also might need to specify ^FH\, here is full example that I have used in the past:

```
^XA
^FO343,295
^BQN,2,4^FH\^FDLA,Field1\09Field2\09Field3\0D^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Comment: I have it almost working perfectly with your ^FH suggestion. Here is what I have now  
  
`^FO400,100 ^BQN,2,10 ^FH\^FDLA,300957\09STORES\096D18\09STORES\09KBLINE\09\0950\09\09\09^FS ^PQ1,0,1,Y `  
  
After the \0950\90\90 I need an ENTER function so it clicks the OK button on the popup that appears in that field before tabbing to the last field. Is there a function that does that too? Thanks again for your help! @Elton

Comment: Try using \0D for Carriage Return

Comment: I tried that. It didnt work. I looked up the ASCII table for the values but the few that seemed like it might use the ENTER/ RETURN function didnt work as needed. @Elton

Comment: Check that you have a zero in front of the D, this is hex.  I just did a quick test and it worked scanning a QR code into Excel.

Comment: yeah, I made sure it was a 0. The popup appears as soon as I tab in to the field, and it appears to set focus on the Ok button on load, so I would imagine my doing a Return it should close the popup. Maybe it isnt actually placing the focus on the button during load. Ill have to keep playing with it. @Elton

Comment: Could be coming through to quick or two slow.  Not sure what type of bar code scanner you are using but check to see if it has an option to lengthen the inter character delay.

Answer (score -3):

_0D_0A to get to next line in QR Code.